# How to set a fixed time range to xAxis in Highstock?

Tags: highcharts

I want to get data from sensors each second and show them in Highstock with a datetime xAxis, it will take a long time to collect data, the default xAxis range is automatically computed by Highstock and it is not fit for me.

My requirement is:

1. keep a fixed range such as 4/8/12 hours whether data is enough or not

I hava tried softMin,softMax, min, max, it didn't work.

2. if collecting time greater then the fixed range, the chart starts scrolling
3. not affect the zoom/panning function

Can Highstock do this? If not, is any other chart recommended?

Comment: I suppose that you should call `setExtremes` (https://api.highcharts.com/class-reference/Highcharts.Axis#setExtremes) after each update of your data. You can use the fetched data to determine the values for `newMin` and `newMax` arguments of `setExtremes`.

Comment: @KamilKulig I need to scale the chart, if  I use this method every time data updated, I must get current scale ratio and then determine the values of newMin and newMax, is there any API to get current scale ratio?

Comment: I don't quite understand what you're trying to accomplish. Could you provide a live demo of your chart (jsfiddle ideally)?

Comment: @KamilKulig for example: I start collecting data at 9:00, I want the initial xAxis time range is 9:00 ~ 12:00, addPoint is called each second, so 9:00 - 12:00 will display 3600 * 3 = 10800 points, if points count less than 10800, the chart will not start scrolling, when last data added at 12:00, the xAxis should be changed to 12:00 ~ 15:00, then the next 10800 points will be added to series in the next three hours.

Comment: @KamilKulig The above requirement can be accomplished using setExtremes, the problem that I confused is how to use it when I scale the chart. When I scroll the mouse wheel, the chart will zoom in or out, in this case, how can I get the default scale ratio? Or how can I handle the zoom event? If I don't get the ratio or the event, I can't determine how to set the new extremes. In additional, I want to get the mouse position when zoom event triggered, so I can use that point as center point to scale current range. I hope my explanation is clear enough and you can understand. Thank you!

Comment: You can catch the zoom event in `xAxis.events.afterSetExtremes`: https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/xAxis.events.afterSetExtremes The argument passed to this callback function contains the information about new extremes. Previous extremes values are saved in axis' `oldMin` & `oldMax` properties.